# Python replacing all uppercase characters in a string with *

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, replace, character

Is there a simple, straightforward way to turn this string:

```
"aBCd3Fg"
```

Into:

```
"a**d3*g"
```

In python 2.7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure how fast you need this, but if you're looking for the fastest solution out there. The python string module's `translate` function is a slightly more roundabout, though generally more performant method:

```
import string

transtab = string.maketrans(string.uppercase, '*'*len(string.uppercase))
"aBCd3Fg".translate(transtab)

>>>'a**d3*g'
```

I'm always surprised about how many people don't know about this trick. One of the best guarded secrets in python IMO

Comment: This would have been my recommendation.

Comment: @mgilson Glad to hear it, less buggy than regex, and 2-5 as fast and also marginally lower complexity.

Answer (score 5):

```
import re

print re.sub(r'[A-Z]', '*', "aBCd3Fg")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string = ''.join(['*' if x.isupper() else x for x in string])
```

Comment: Fun fact: If you long for a C-style conditional operator, you can shorten your expression `'*' if r == r.upper() else r` with the equivalent `(r,'*')[r.isupper()]`.

Comment: @DarrenStone - That will remove the short-circuiting property of the ternary as well as take longer to process. :)

Comment: @DarrenStone, I know about this syntax but it is usually frowned upon by most python users.

Comment: @Smac89 - Well said.  I'm one of them. :)  However, you _can_ improve your code's efficiency by using a list comprehension instead of a generator expression.  Here is a [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/2555451).

Comment: @Smac89, fair enough. I prefer the terser expression but to each their own. Any reason you wouldn't use `r.isupper()`?

Comment: @iCodez, thanks. You forced me to check the performance hit.  It's longer, for sure, so thanks for the heads-up.  `$ python -m timeit "''.join(['*' if x.isupper() else x for x in 'abcDEFhji123'])"` -->
`100000 loops, best of 3: 4.07 usec per loop`, while `$ python -m timeit "''.join([(x,'*')[x.isupper()] for x in 'abcDEFhji123'])"` --> `100000 loops, best of 3: 4.93 usec per loop`.

Comment: The join generator vs list-comp thing is pretty well known.  However, I've never seen anyone do the test with a different python implemenation than Cpython.  And really, the time difference is pretty  negligible.  As a matter of style, I prefer the generator, only swapping to the list-comp if I know that this is a bottleneck in the code.

Comment: @DarrenStone - You're welcome.  In simple terms, the reason your method is slower is that it has to 1) evaluate `r.isupper()`, 2) interpret that evaluation as an integer, 3) build the tuple `(r,'*')`, and 4) index that tuple with the result of `r.isupper()`.  The ternary however just evaluates `r.isupper()`.  Moreover, the `else r` part will _only_ be run if `if r.isupper()` returns `False`.  For more info, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/ternary-conditional-operator-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution :

```
input = "aBCd3Fg"
output = "".join(['*' if 'A' <= char <= 'Z' else char for char in input ])
#Long version
input = "aBCd3Fg"
output = ''
for char in input:
    output = output + '*' if ord('A') <= ord(char) <= ord('Z') else output + char
print output
```

Answer (score -3):

You can also do:

```
for x in myString:
    if (x == 'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M',
    'N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'"
        x = '*'
```

That's a short piece of code that will do the work.

Comment: Why all the negative feedback ? Isn't it a legit answer ?

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but this answer is not so short, and won't do the work as it's showed.